# checking IDs of buttons

Tags: java, android

[image]

As it is shown in the image, the 2 IDs are not equal, according to logcat, however, the program goes inside IF clause anyway. What is the problem? Do I miss some property of button ids?

P.S. This part of code goes through the table of buttons and finds the coodinates of the clicked button, buttonId is the id of the clicked button. Thank you!

Comment: hehe `if(theId == buttonId);`  NO SEMI-COLON! :)  `if(theId == buttonId)`

Comment: For future debugging: you've *assumed* the comparison is true, but you're not looking at the comparison itself. Always check your assumptions.

Comment: @3kings You should post that as an answer

Comment: @CurlyCorvus there ya go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

`if(theId == buttonId);`

to

`if(theId == buttonId)`

No semi-colon after if statements

Comment: oh god, i gave up 2 times on this error, that was too simple, thank you!